# Debugging Visual Studio Setup Project

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, debugging, deployment, setup-project

I'm a few months into building a game and I decided to release something for people to have a play with so I could get some feedback. However I'm getting a lot of reports like this:

> I got a problem with the setup, when is at 95% it suddenly goes to 0%
>   and says installation cancelled

This has occurred on Windows XP and Windows 7.

This is a visual studio installer, with the primary output from the game and all the content added. I've made sure that all the referenced projects (except system and XNA ones) are set to "Copy local" in the game project. I've made sure that the installer has "Microsoft .net Framework 4 Client Profile (x86 and x64)", "Microsoft XNA Framework Redistributable 4.0" as prerequisites.

What could possibly cause this?

If it helps, [here](http://placeholder-software.co.uk/HeistGameSetup.zip) is the installer so you can try it yourself.

Comment: Is it an MSI? Then run `msiexec /i foo.msi /L*v foo.log`

Comment: The problem I have is that I can't reproduce this problem locally, is there a way to make the installer automatically do this so I just have to tell people to run it and send me the log file when it fails?

Comment: You could bundle the .msi with a script that does the above and tell users to try that and send in the resulting log file.

Comment: The only problem I can see with a script is that the setup project produces both a setup.exe and a GameInstaller.msi - you're meant to run the setup.exe first which installs prerequisites. If my script directly launches GameInstaller.msi it's going to skip that bootstrapping stage.

Comment: You can enable MSI logging globally: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/223300

Comment: XNA games are simple enough that IExpress can be an adequate installer. Also, the VS installer is being discontinued (a good thing), so I recommend the WiX toolset for most installer packages.

Comment: Why's it a good thing? WiX looks a lot more complex for a simple situation like this.

Answer (score 1):

If you're having difficulty with an MSI installation, you can get an installer log:

```
msiexec /i foo.msi /L*v foo.log
```

The log file is quite verbose, and a bit hard to read, but should give you some pointers.

If you're not running the .msi directly (it's a bootstrapper, or a push deployment from something like ConfigMgr), you can turn on global MSI logging: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314852 (turn it off when you're finished).

Comment: What would be the best way to turn logging on and off again when the installation starts and stops?

Comment: It logs every installation on the machine, so it'll use up disk space. Just turn it on manually, do your installation, and then turn it off manually.